Rain cloud data was implemented semi-successfully on the map. The map was not visible
problem is Floating a map (successful), floating rain cloud data on the map (successful), but the visualized rain cloud data obscures the map.


this code is python
What I tried
Implement a method to set the transparency of the map to 50%
Overlay a semi-transparent map on top of the map using the Canvas widget
Use the 
#update_map_overlay 
method to capture a map image, dim it, set transparency, and display it 
on the canvas.
This will make the precipitation overlay and map visible together. I am using ImageGrab to capture 
images of a map.
But I only see a white screen

A different approach was used

Instead of adding a translucent rainfall layer on top of the map,
I directly drew an image with the transparency of the map adjusted.
To achieve this, we used Pillow to make the image transparent and drew it on #Tkinter's Canvas.

But still white screen

A different approach was used

To implement a way to display map and radar overlay together without using Canvas.
, The approach was to set the radar tile of tkintermapview and adjust the transparency.
Although tkintermapview itself does not have an option to adjust the transparency of radar tiles,
Instead of adjusting the transparency of map tiles, you can change the background of the entire UI,
including the map.

But still white screen

use a different approach

To display the map and radar overlay together, we will use #Basemap (mpl_toolkits.basemap) 
and Matplotlib to draw the map and display it in #Tkinter.

Bug
use a different approach
Implement this by drawing a map using #cartopy and #matplotlib and integrating it with #Tkinter.
failure
I tried various methods other than this, but they all failed due to my lack of skills.
this is code
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import requests
import tkintermapview
import math

class WeatherRadar:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("WRS")
        self.root.state('zoomed')

        self.create_top_section()
        self.create_bottom_section()
        self.overlay_global_rainfall()  #비구름 데이터

    def create_top_section(self):
        top_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, expand=False)

        # 날씨 정보 표시
        self.track_temp_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Track Temp: N/A")
        self.track_temp_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.humidity_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Humidity: N/A")
        self.humidity_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.air_temp_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Air Temp: N/A")
        self.air_temp_label.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.wind_speed_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Wind Speed: N/A")
        self.wind_speed_label.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        wind_frame = ttk.Frame(top_frame)
        wind_frame.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.wind_direction_label = ttk.Label(wind_frame, text="Wind Direction: N/A")
        self.wind_direction_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.wind_direction_canvas = tk.Canvas(wind_frame, width=50, height=50)
        self.wind_direction_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Rain forecast
        self.rain_forecast_entry_eta_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Rain ETA: N/A")
        self.rain_forecast_entry_eta_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.rain_forecast_exit_eta_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Rain Exit ETA: N/A")
        self.rain_forecast_exit_eta_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.rain_intensity_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Rain Intensity: N/A mm/h")
        self.rain_intensity_label.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def create_bottom_section(self):
        bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        bottom_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # 지도 표시
        self.map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(bottom_frame, corner_radius=0)
        self.map_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.map_widget.set_zoom(16)  # 초기 줌 레벨을 16으로 설정하여 더 확대된 상태로 시작

    def fetch_weather_data(self, lat, lon):
        api_key = " api key "
        url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={api_key}&units=metric"
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            track_temp = data['main']['temp']
            humidity = data['main']['humidity']
            air_temp = data['main']['feels_like']
            wind_speed = data['wind']['speed']
            wind_deg = data['wind']['deg']

            self.track_temp_label.config(text=f"Track Temp: {track_temp}°C")
            self.humidity_label.config(text=f"Humidity: {humidity}%")
            self.air_temp_label.config(text=f"Air Temp: {air_temp}°C")
            self.wind_speed_label.config(text=f"Wind Speed: {wind_speed} m/s")
            self.wind_direction_label.config(text=f"Wind Direction: {wind_deg}°")

            self.update_wind_direction_canvas(wind_deg)

            # For now, setting rain forecast to N/A
            self.rain_forecast_entry_eta_label.config(text="Rain ETA: N/A")
            self.rain_forecast_exit_eta_label.config(text="Rain Exit ETA: N/A")
            self.rain_intensity_label.config(text="Rain Intensity: N/A mm/h")
        else:
            print("Failed to fetch weather data")

    def overlay_global_rainfall(self):
        # OpenWeatherMap 레이더 타일 URL 패턴
        radar_tile_url = "https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/precipitation_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid="
        self.map_widget.set_tile_server(radar_tile_url)

    def update_wind_direction_canvas(self, wind_deg):
        self.wind_direction_canvas.delete("all")
        center_x, center_y = 25, 25
        length = 20
        angle_rad = math.radians(wind_deg)

        end_x = center_x + length * math.cos(angle_rad)
        end_y = center_y - length * math.sin(angle_rad)

        self.wind_direction_canvas.create_line(center_x, center_y, end_x, end_y, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="blue", width=2)

       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = WeatherRadar(root)
    root.mainloop()





I still got a blank map. Using Python 3.12.4

To use the map, you must enter your OpenWeather Map API key into your code. You need to put radar_tile_url = "appi(d your api)" in def overlay_global_rainfall and "api key" in def fetch weather data
